# How to run a java program on Apache Spark Cluster?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I followed "A Standalone App in Java" part of the tutorial https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.8.1/quick-start.html

This part worked as expected

```
$ mvn package
$ mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="SimpleApp"
...
Lines with a: 46, Lines with b: 23
```

How can I run the same class on the Cluster in parallel ? If I can pass this step I will use HDFS data as input.
Is it possible to run this SimpleApp.java with parameters like this:

```
./run-example <class> <params>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to write simple Java or Scala class in your IDE. Create SparkConf and SparkContext objects in your "SimpleApp.java".

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster("local[2]");
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
```

Once you run `maven clean package` or `maven package` it will create jar file in your project's target folder. If it doesn't then create a JAR file using following command. You can find the SimpleApp.class file in **"target/classes"** folder. cd to this directory.

```
jar cfve file.jar SimpleApp.class
```

Put this JAR file into your project in target directory. This JAR file contains the dependency of your SimpleApp class while submitting your job to Spark. I guess you have project structure like below.

```
simpleapp
 - src/main/java
  - org.apache.spark.examples
    -SimpleApp.java
 - lib
  - dependent.jars (you can put all dependent jars inside lib directory)
 - target
  - simpleapp.jar (after compiling your source)
```

cd to your spark directory. I am using spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6. Your cmd looks like this.

```
spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6>
```

Start the master and worker using following commands.

```
spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6> ./sbin/start-all.sh
```

If this does not work then start master and slaves separately.

```
spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6> ./sbin/start-master.sh
spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6> ./sbin/start-slaves.sh
```

Submit your spark program using Spark Submit. If you have structure like I explained then pass this argument in class.

```
--class org.apache.spark.examples.SimpleApp
```

else

```
--class SimpleApp
```

Finally submit your spark program through spark submit.

```
spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6>./bin/spark-submit --class SimpleApp --master local[2] /PATH-TO-YOUR-PROJECT-DIRECTORY/target/file.jar
```

Here I have used **local[2] as a master** so my program will run on two threads but you can pass your master URL in --master as a `--master spark://YOUR-HOSTNAME:7077`

Port number 7077 is a default port number for Master URL.

Comment: But how master know about slaves location/configuration  as both are separate `start-master.sh` and `start-slaves.sh` shell script  ? Where are we specifying number of slaves required ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't run them with mvn, I just build a fat jar, scp it to the cluster, then run:

```
java -cp /path/to/jar.jar com.yourcompany.yourpackage.YourApp some arguments
```

Comment: I am getting the error in the screenshot1 when I run from the fat jar. TestApp.java is shown in screenshot2. Hope you can help me with this. 

screenshot1 : http://oi60.tinypic.com/9qgttz.jpg

screenshot2 :  http://oi58.tinypic.com/mc3oyr.jpg